# How to cancel selected option in a select list when user confirm false (cancel)

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this JavaScript code:

```
function change(varam){
    if(confirm("Select this option?"))
    {

    } else {
        if(varam=="1")
        {
            alert("Return selected to NO");
        } else {
            alert("Return selected to YES");
        }
    }

}
```

And the HTML code:

```
<select id="sel" name="sel" onchange="change(this.value)">
    <option value="1">YES</option>
    <option value="0">NO</option>
</select>
```

**What I want:**

Suppose  the selected default is **YES**.  If the user selects **NO**, appear confirmation boxes if he wants to change to **NO** or not,  if the choice is "OK",  the option **NO** will be selected,  if the choice is "CANCEL" then **NO** option is not selected, but back  to the **YES** option are selected. And vice versa.

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CtxUy/

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/CtxUy/1/

Comment: @ExplosionPills : Yes like that. Thank you for the solution. I did not know it turned out simple :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only ever concerned about these two elements, you can just set the values manually:

```
if(varam=="1")
{
    document.getElementById('sel').value = 0;
} else {
    document.getElementById('sel').value = 1;
}
```

If there are potentially other values, what you can do is keep track of the initially selected value and set the selector value back to that when they refuse to confirm, or overwrite that stored value if they do confirm.

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/CtxUy/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the options and select the one that has the `selected` attribute. If none has it, select the first one (which is always the default in absence of the `selected` attribute).

```
var select = document.getElementById('sel');
var options = select.options;
options[0].selected = true; // preemptively select the first option

for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (options[i].hasAttribute('selected')) {
        options[i].selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f5jbF/)

**Reference:** [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement), [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLOptionElement).

Comment: Thanks, but your answer yet as I want.